# How to filter an SQL Database using a range and display it on a ListView

Tags: android, sql, database, android-studio, listview

I'm fairly new to Android Studio, so excuse me for my inexperience.

I've created an SQL database with each data-set containing a id, metal name, and melting point.

I want to be able to filter the database and only display the data-set which has a melting point within the max and min values provided.

The user types in the max and min using two EditTexts. Then clicks a button to open a separate activity with a ListView populated by the database.

The code I have written so far does nothing and prints the same original database without filtering.

Filter Activity (if max and min values are not set, 10000 and 0 are set, respectively):

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMaxInput.getText()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMinInput.getText())){
                double maxMP = Double.parseDouble(mpMaxInput.getText().toString());
                double minMP = Double.parseDouble(mpMinInput.getText().toString());
                myDB.filterData(maxMP,minMP);
                startActivity(mas);
            }

            else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMaxInput.getText()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMinInput.getText())){
                double maxMP = 10000;
                double minMP = Double.parseDouble(mpMinInput.getText().toString());
                myDB.filterData(maxMP,minMP);
                startActivity(mas);
            }
            else if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMaxInput.getText()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMinInput.getText())){
               double maxMP = Double.parseDouble(mpMaxInput.getText().toString());
                double minMP = 0;
                myDB.filterData(maxMP,minMP);
                startActivity(mas);
                }
            else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMaxInput.getText()) && TextUtils.isEmpty(mpMinInput.getText())){
                double maxMP = 10000;
                double minMP = 0;
                myDB.filterData(maxMP,minMP);
                startActivity(mas);
               }
        }
    });
```

DisplayListView Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mas);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_back_in, R.anim.activity_back_out);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    openDB();
    populateListView();


}@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

private void openDB(){
    myDB = new DBHandler(this);
    myDB.open();
}

private void closeDB(){
    myDB.close();
}

private void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{DBHandler.ALLOY_NAME, DBHandler.MELTING_POINT};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{R.id.textView48, R.id.textView49};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdaptor;
    myCursorAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.item_layout, cursor, fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);

    ListView list = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list.setAdapter(myCursorAdaptor);

}
```

DBAdapter:

```
public Cursor filterData(double max, double min){
    String query;
    query = "SELECT * FROM '" + DBHandler.TABLE_ALLOY_DETAILS + "' WHERE '" + MELTING_POINT + "' BETWEEN '" + min + "' AND '" + max + "' ";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            if(c!= null){
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need to add OnTextListener for real time filtering

Comment: How would I implement that for two different filters (ie. max and min). And if I'm clicking a button to another activity, why would it need to be real-time?

Comment: First of all why do you need 2 activies? can't you use fragments?activities anhd you could use addOhnTextListener if you are updating the database to the user while they are typing.

Comment: I don't want that. They're entering two different values, and they need both values to update the database, not just one. And if I was using OnTextListener, how would I apply my filter in that scenario?

Comment: I would just create another table and pass in your existing table to a bunch of If statements based on filtering criteria. Then add it to another table. Then use this table as your filtered data. Thats what worked well for me. I have a filter based on time. So I look through my entire table then if both conditions (start and stop time) are met I add this data to my other table.